# Bilinear filtering by sampling corners of a texel

Tags: android, opengl-es2

I'm trying to do bilinear filtering in texels to get the convoluted value of a 3x3 block. Implemented as below:

```
offsetx = 1/width
offsety = 1/height
```

Fragment shader:

```
"varying vec2 vTextureCoord;\n" +
"uniform samplerExternalOES sTexture;\n" +
" vec2 scale = vec2(offsetx,offsety);\n" +
" vec4 p00 = texture2D(sTexture, vTextureCoord + 0.5*scale*vec2(-1,-1));\n" +
" vec4 p02 = texture2D(sTexture, vTextureCoord + 0.5*scale*vec2(1,-1));\n" +
" vec4 p20 = texture2D(sTexture, vTextureCoord + 0.5*scale*vec2(-1,1));\n" +
" vec4 p22 = texture2D(sTexture, vTextureCoord + 0.5*scale*vec2(1,1));\n" +
" vec4 pconvolve = 0.25*(p00 + p02 + p20 + p22);\n" +
```

Vertex shader:

```
private final String mVertexShader =
            "uniform mat4 uMVPMatrix;\n" +
            "uniform mat4 uSTMatrix;\n" +
            "attribute vec4 aPosition;\n" +
            "attribute vec4 aTextureCoord;\n" +
            "varying vec2 vTextureCoord;\n" +
            "void main() {\n" +
            "  gl_Position = uMVPMatrix * aPosition;\n" +
            "  vTextureCoord = (uSTMatrix * aTextureCoord).xy;\n" +
            "}\n";
```

where Matrices are unity matrices and position and texture cordinates are :

```
private final float[] mTriangleVerticesData = {
            // X, Y, Z, U, V
            -1.0f, -1.0f, 0, 0.f, 0.f,
            1.0f, -1.0f, 0, 1.f, 0.f,
            -1.0f,  1.0f, 0, 0.f, 1.f,
            1.0f,  1.0f, 0, 1.f, 1.f,
    };
```

Texture filtering:

```
GLES20.glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR);
GLES20.glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR);
```

Issue:

I have an original implementation where I calculate a convoluted value of a 3x3 block using a Gaussian-Blur algorithm that uses `GL_NEAREST` as texture mapping.
For optimization, I thought of replacing the 3x3 Gaussian Blur with sampling on 4 corners of the texel (as that is also having same weightage). Here I used `GL_LINEAR`.

The expectation was that the results I get from these 2 approaches should not vary by a wide range. But I got a huge difference. Visually both looks almost the same.

I tried changing the first texture mapping to `GL_LINEAR` and compared. That also resulted in a difference. (A difference in R, G and B component values between 2 approaches up to 5 was acceptable.) I got about 45 in some cases.

Testing methodology:

For the same frame, I used glreadPixels and compared the RGB value for all pixels in both cases. Most of them were same, but some showed huge difference:

```
Gaussian        9BD6DA 

Bilinear        8BC0C3
```

Comment: This could happen if vTextureCoord is not in the center of a texel — then the samples around it won't be at the corners as you expect. This is consistent with this symptom: "I tried changing the first texture mapping toGL_LINEAR and compared. That also resulted in a difference" — if you're sampling at texel centers, Linear and Nearest should be identical. This suggests that all your texture coordinates are subtly shifted relative to a direct blit. This problem is probably in your vertex shader, which you haven't shown here.

Comment: Please post the resulting images

Comment: @DMGregory : I have edited the question to include vertexShader. Do you have any suggestions on how to get around this problem.?

Comment: Still stuck in the issue. How can I ensure that I am sampling from texel center itself.